# optionMenu textColor Action HoneyComb

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, textcolor

I'm searching a solution to change textColor of the Option menu items of the HoneyComb's actionBar when items have :

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

I try a lot of different solutions but none works on my project ...
Can someone help me?

Here's what I put in the file `style.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="theme.app" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="@style/ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanc</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarSubTitle" parent="@style/ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanc</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*P.S. : Sorry if there are any spelling mistakes but I'm a french.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just have `android:actionMenuTextColor` in the wrong place. It's an attribute on the theme, not the action bar style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#f00</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

A few other things:

- You can learn a lot about where styles/attributes belong by looking in `<sdk>/platforms/android-13/data/res/values/`, specifically at `attrs.xml`, `themes.xml`, and `styles.xml`.
- You can also use `android:actionMenuTextAppearance` to provide a text appearance (a collection of size/style/color/etc. information) all at once.
- It doesn't make sense for your `ActionBarTitle` style to have `@style/ActionBar` as a parent style.

Comment: Does this affect text color of the items in the overflow menu? Can them be styled except for the background? And will it work both with and without hardware menu key?